# auth internal-error during the time of registration, in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with the registration of the new user in `Firebase` Web. It gives me the following error :

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid
>   API key.","errors":[{"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid
>   API
>   key.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

Error code:

```
auth/internal-error
```

I can login the users easily if I create the user from `Firebase` manually and they can also logout from the website.

I have updated the `API key` from the project in Firebase.

They code I'm using for the registration of the user:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailIdOfTheUser, passwordOfTheUser).then(function(){

    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log(`HERE IS THE USER ID ON REGISTRATION ===> ${uid}`);


    //SET THE KEY AND VALUE ABOVE
    firebase.database().ref("users/").child(uid).set({

      email: user.email,
      userId: userIdOfTheUser,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumberOfTheUser,
    });

}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      console.log(`error ====> ${errorMessage}

      with error code ====> ${errorCode}`);

      console.log(`The Id is ===> ${emailIdOfTheUser}
      Password is ===> ${passwordOfTheUser}
      ReMatch Password id ===> ${confirmPassworddOfTheUser}`); 
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: got answer? please share. I'm facing the same problem